# Node.js React.js + Google OAuth2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, oauth, google-authenticator

У меня связка `React.js` - фронт и `Node.js` - бэк. Задача заключается в идентификации пользователей через **Google** аккаунт. Т.е. добавить **Google** авторизацию.

Находил модули **Google** авторизации для реакта и для ноды. Не понятно использовать их лил нет, или только на фронте, тогда что передавать на бек....

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать авторизацию и привязывать к пользователю другие объекты из таблиц?

Comment: Вам понадобятся модуль аутентификации под node js и база данных. База данных нужна хранения сессии, и если понадобится, для сохранения данных пользователей. Посоветую использовать http://passportjs.org/, там есть модуль для гугловской авторизации + mongo db